# how to increase carousel image space?

Tags: android, carousel

I downloaded sample android carousel demo source code in below link [carousel demo source code link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel)

my doubt is if I add more images, images gap is very low so how to increase images space and one more doubt bottom image reflection is hide how to get bottom reflection image.....

this is my xml source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:pj="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.carouseldemo.main"
    xmlns:bm="com.carouseldemo.main"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        >
            <com.carouseldemo.controls.Carousel
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/carousel"  
                pj:UseReflection="true"
                pj:Items="@array/entries"
                pj:SelectedItem="0"
                android:animationDuration="200"
            />      
    </LinearLayout>     
</LinearLayout>
```

pls see my screen shot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be defined in **Carousel.java** file.  Please check the following functions in

> src/com/carouseldemo/controls/Carousel.java

```
getChildStaticTransformation  
makeAndAddView  
setUpChild  
Calculate3DPosition
```

Comment: Please post the things which you have modified, so that the users with same problem can find this useful.

Comment: me too facing same problem can you send me the code @Hasmukh

Comment: @prabhakaran Did you get solution of it?

Answer (score 3):

I modified the code in `Calculate3DPosition` to include the usage of a NEW `verticalStretchFactor` in the calculation of the `y`:

Calculate3DPosition

```
 float y = -getHeight()/2f + (float) (diameter/mVerticalStretchFactor * z * android.util.FloatMath.sin(mTheta));
```

I added this new attribute parameter to the attrs of the control. I found a factor on the order of 140f worked well on a standard Droid Phone display to provide more vertical spacing between the items in the list. I was using the control as a Home Menu control and only had 5 to 6 items in the list.

Comment: what is the value of mVerticalStretchFactor?

Comment: same question any one help me how to calculate mVerticalStretchFactor ?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your answers, especially Sen ,lepert.. I fix the issue of false selection of click with large images .Your solution is very much useful if the user needs to get the images untouched only but the issue still remains .

If any one need to make the spinner images untouched as given like the sample image given above by Balaji ,Use Sen's and lepert solution.

And if you want to make the images beneth the main one and get clicks /selections correctly change the code as given below ..This works for me ..

Change in

pointToPosition(int x, int y) in CorousalSpinner.java no need to change the code given by the above solutions

replace

```
Collections.sort(fitting);

        if(fitting.size() != 0)
            return fitting.get(0).getIndex();
        else
            return mSelectedPosition;
```

with

```
Collections.sort(fitting);

if(fitting.size() != 0){
    if(fitting.size()>1){
        return fitting.get((fitting.size()-1)).getIndex();
    }else{
        return fitting.get(0).getIndex();   
    }


}
else{
    return mSelectedPosition;
}
```

Comment: I found whereever i touched, the selected one was always the "same selected item" if I didn't rotate it. How Did you resolve this problem? Thanks.