# 3D Carousel in Android

Tags: android, 3d, carousel

I am working on 3D Carousel for android.

I am using this [code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel) and the following is my current output.

[image]

I want to develop the following 3D shaped carousel.

[image]

I refered to the following questions which are already asked in SO.

1. [How to do 3d Carousel with modifications in image's dimensions and angle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268674/how-to-do-3d-carousel-with-modifications-in-images-dimensions-and-angle)
2. [How to create list with carousel effect in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19508936/how-to-create-list-with-carousel-effect-in-android)
3. [how to increase carousel image space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449546/how-to-increase-carousel-image-space)
4. [Coverflow Carousel effect same as iPhone/iPad in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20677100/coverflow-carousel-effect-same-as-iphone-ipad-in-android)

The following is near to my requirement:

5. [Using 3d Carousel project to create SPB Carousel style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726377/using-3d-carousel-project-to-create-spb-carousel-style)

From this I answer I put:

```
mCamera.rotateY(-((CarouselItem) child).getCurrentAngle());
```

inside `getChildStaticTransformation()` method of `Carousel.java` but I'm not getting a perfect result.

Please help me to solve it.

Comment: Can you upload the complete code to github or something similiar so I can have a look?

Comment: I am also looking for something similar to this..
Scroll Speed should also be a concern here, because the referred 3d carousel project has some blazing fast scrolling speed even on a tiny scroll.

Comment: I will take a look at this Question on this weekend, Insha Allah.

Comment: What are you trying to do? I get what you've done but not what youre trying to do, the question is not clear.

Comment: The rotation must depend on sinus of the angle, so multiply with `Math.sin(angle)`

Comment: though this is iOS focused but the explanation for the math might help you: http://www.thinkandbuild.it/introduction-to-3d-drawing-in-core-animation-part-2/

Comment: @dreamsneverdie, did you ever get this working?

Comment: No buddy. didnt find perfect. but i have solved with little bit different.

Comment: can you please share the updated code

Answer (score 2):

You are using a function called Calculate3DPosition which calculates X, Y, Z positions from the angle and then those are used in a matrix.translate call.

What you need is actually much simpler - you just need to call matrix.rotate with the angle.  It might look surprisingly easy when you've finished, but honestly, the only complexity in the 3D code you have copied is from attempting to keep everything facing the user instead of letting it rotate ...