# How can I zoom the central item in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, carousel, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` and I need to enlarge only the center item with animation.

I have to change it's size:

- Increase when it appears.
- Decrease to normal, when it goes away.

It is something like carousel, I need to achieve this effect with `RecyclerView`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Show us the code you've written so far.

Comment: I haven't written something special yet, because I can't understand how to achieve this functionality. I saw some carousel examples with the horizontal scrollviews, some kind of self-made solutions with extending the view class and viewpager, but nothing about what I wrote up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been trying something close to what you're trying and have found these links very useful. You can extend the classes there to suit your need:-

https://github.com/Azoft/CarouselLayoutManager (this is what i've used in my application)

[3D Carousel in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20883849/3d-carousel-in-android) (this could perhaps give you more of an idea)

Comment: Regarding CarouselLayoutManager, Is there any similar control available for iOS?

Comment: I'm sorry i don't have any experience on iOS and can't help you with the same