# Customize Recycler View ROw

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to create a recycler view like this. Is this possible in android.If so please help me out with some tutorials.

Just edits:
Its a recycler view. Each element of the recycler view is an ImageView. The text "selected " written for everyone to understand that this item is selected / highlighted. While you can notice that the highlighted item is taller than the rest of the items and has a different background color. To be clear I am looking for something like the below video. Is it possible ? 
[Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k-jp6b2lCmk)

[image]

Comment: *please help me out with some tutorials* --> **NO**. [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I have been searching a lot on this. But couldn't find anything. First of all I want to know IS THIS POSSIBLE ?

Comment: it seems to be carousal kind of stuff the layout which u mentioned is not clear but if its carousal the same as  itunes u can search for it on net

Comment: It seems a TextView with a colorful background (9 patch or LayerList).

Comment: @NiranjanBalkrishnaPrajapati Thanx a lot for the name

Comment: possible duplicate of [3D Carousel in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20883849/3d-carousel-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

After what i got from @Niranjan Prajapati's comment. I found out the same question here [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20883849/3d-carousel-in-android) and the tutorial link too. So I suppose its time for me to close this one.