# How can i swipe through recyclerview items in a manner similar to a viewpager?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I've been trying to implement a recyclerView to function similar to a ViewPager by displaying one item at a time. I looked at https://github.com/lsjwzh/RecyclerViewPager and found it useful. I basically want to implement a vertical ViewPager using recyclerView wherein each item overlaps over the other during transitions. Should i be looking at inter-item animations? And if so, I would appreciate any help that i could get.
Or should I just stick to a ViewPager? (My apprehensions about ViewPager are that it may be slower than a recyclerView)

Comment: You could try this library https://github.com/lsjwzh/RecyclerViewPager

Comment: Yes, I did try that. But as i said, i need a different sort of transition between items - something which imitates a viewpager

Comment: Sorry i didn't read the library reference, if you don't want to use ViewPager i think you'll need to extend RecyclerView, disable scroll and add a SwipeGesture to enable paging. About animation, you'll have to move programmatically the RecyclerView according touch swipe coordinates

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it

Answer (score 0):

You can try this project I did for Udacity Android Nanodegree.
This holds a similar functionallity:

https://github.com/sprengerst/udacity_nanodegree_project_5

There, a Viewerpager is populated by Fragments which are then populated by a Loader.

Comment: I looked into your project, but again this is not what i want to achieve. I want to view only one item of the recyclerview at a time per page. But i want to show the transitions from one item to the other as fragment transitions.

Comment: Sorry for my missunderstanding, but isn't the DetailView of each article such a thing? The Detailview is handled by Fragments in a Viewerpager, which make the Articles horicontal swipeable? So you see one full article at a time but can swipe through all articles.

Comment: I'm sorry for not having explained what i want clearly enough. I basically want to implement a vertical ViewPager using recyclerView wherein each item overlaps over the other during transitions

Comment: @Vijeet Vergis so you want vertical scrollable fragments with animation?

Comment: Maybe this link could help you for the vertical part: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22797619/2522174

Comment: And here is a guide to make transition to a viewerpager object. I'm not sure if the vertical edition is easy to combine with animations. http://blog.rhesoft.com/2015/03/20/tutorial-viewpagertransforms-library-animations-for-transforming-viewpager-on-android-studio/

Comment: No, but they are cardview items consisiting of an imageview and a textview. they work sort of similar to this https://github.com/lsjwzh/RecyclerViewPager.

Comment: What I'm able to achieve till now is a vertical viewPager along with each item taking up a whole page. What i want to achieve is the overlapping effect on this

Comment: So you mean like the Itunes Mediatek a cover in the middle an the other items left and right?

Comment: Maybe this could help then: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20883849/2522174

Comment: Sort of like that, but instead the other items would be up and down instead of left and right

Comment: Thank you for all the time you took to help me with my query. I'll look into it

Comment: Ah ok. I think this library could be the right one. https://github.com/Azoft/CarouselLayoutManager

Comment: No problem:) maybe I will need it one day too.

Comment: Let me know how you doin.