# Android Image Gallery layout design

Tags: android, android-layout, image-gallery

Please help me in a doubt regarding Image gallery. The regular image gallery is usually found to be in a linear or straight line way i.e one image after another along a straight line. Is it possible somehow to display the images revolving around a circular path. Like below:

[image]

Comment: search for Cricular carousel android... you will get answer....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [3D Carousel in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20883849/3d-carousel-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

used this link...

https://github.com/ludovicroland/carousel-android

Gradle

```
 compile 'fr.rolandl:carousel:1.0.1@aar'
```

Maven

```
<dependency>
<groupId>fr.rolandl</groupId>
<artifactId>carousel</artifactId>
<version>1.0.1</version>
<type>aar</type>
</dependency>
```

As Library Project

Alternatively, check out this repository and add it as a library project.

$ git clone https://github.com/ludovicroland/carousel-android.git
Import the project into your favorite IDE and add android.library.reference.1=/path/to/carousel-android/library to your project.properties.

Layout

You need to declare the Carousel directly into your layout.

```
<fr.rolandl.carousel.Carousel
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/carousel"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:animationDuration="200"
 />
```

Items

An item should be associated with a business object (a classical pojo), for example:

```
public final class Photo
implements Serializable
{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public final String name;

public final String image;

 public Photo(String name, String image)
 {
this.name = name;
this.image = image;
}

}
```

with a specific layout, for example:

```
 <TextView
 android:id="@+id/name"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:textColor="@android:color/black"
 />
```

and with a CarouselItem that should override the extractView and update methods :

```
  public final class PhotoItem
  extends CarouselItem<Photo>
  {

 private ImageView image;

 private TextView name;

 private Context context;

    public PhotoItem(Context context)
   {
   super(context, R.layout.item);
   this.context = context;
   }

  @Override
 public void extractView(View view)
 {
   image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
   name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
 }

@Override
public void update(Photo photo)
 {
  image.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier(photo.image, "drawable", context.getPackageName()));
  name.setText(photo.name);
}

  }
```

Adapter

You also have to create your own adapter that takes a list of business object in its constructor:

```
 public final class MyAdapter
extends CarouselAdapter<Photo>
{

 public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Photo> photos)
{
  super(context, photos);
 }

 @Override
 public CarouselItem<Photo> getCarouselItem(Context context)
 {
  return new PhotoItem(context);
}

 }
```

In the Activity/Fragment

In the activity or the fragment that uses the carousel, you can find its reference:

```
 final Carousel carousel; = (Carousel) findViewById(R.id.carousel);
 create your list of business objects:

 final List<Photo> photos = new ArrayList<>();
 photos.add(new Photo("Photo1", "fotolia_40649376"));
photos.add(new Photo("Photo2", "fotolia_40973414"));
photos.add(new Photo("Photo3", "fotolia_48275073"));
photos.add(new Photo("Photo4", "fotolia_50806609"));
photos.add(new Photo("Photo5", "fotolia_61643329"));
```

create an instance of your adapter:

```
 final CarouselAdapter adapter = adapter = new MyAdapter(this, photos);
carousel.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Listeners

You can also use some listeners on the carousel.

The OnItemClickListener:

```
  carousel.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
  {

   @Override
   public void onItemClick(CarouselBaseAdapter<?> carouselBaseAdapter, View view, int position, long id)
   {
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The item '" + position + "' has been clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    carousel.scrollToChild(position);
    }

 });
```

The OnItemLongClickListener:

```
   carousel.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener()
    {

  @Override
  public boolean onItemLongClick(CarouselBaseAdapter<?> carouselBaseAdapter, View view, int position, long id)
   {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The item '" + position + "' has been long clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    carousel.scrollToChild(position);
    return false;
   }

   });
```

see also this link..

https://github.com/panhuachao/Android-3D-Carousel

Comment: Thank you for your response Er. Arjun saini ... Let me try this out. Will post about response

Answer (score 0):

We need to create 2 xml file, 1) for Oval drawable and 2) for layout design. Create below 2 files and add that into your project.

> drwbl_ovalview.xml (res --> drawable)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <stroke
        android:width="5dp"
        android:color="#5EC7F1" />
</shape>
```

> activity_main.xml (res --> layout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgvw_ovalview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_margin="25dp"
            android:src="@drawable/drwbl_ovalview"
            android:contentDescription="Images"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgvw_yahoo"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:src="@drawable/yahoo_icon"
            android:contentDescription="Yahoo images"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgvw_messenger"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/messenger_icon"
            android:contentDescription="Messenger images"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgvw_google"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:src="@drawable/google_icon"
            android:contentDescription="Google images"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgvw_facebook"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:src="@drawable/facebook_icon"
            android:contentDescription="Facbook image"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Review screenshot of above code**
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer Jaldeep Asodariya. But i guess you got my query wrong. I was looking for a solution as mentioned in gallery perspective.

Comment: Thanks @bharatkumar and sorry for misunderstanding.